# Confirm Subscription plan from play Store Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, subscription, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am implementing subscription using flutter_inapp_purchase plugin.
All is working fine. I am facing case here that when App is not opened and i tried to resubscribe an expire subscription from play store it's showing confirm plan and giving option to open app.

How to manage this listener from app and complete purchase ?
Please refer below image that showing the option when i tried to resubscribe an expired subscription(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORgR6.png)]
Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I' not sure about the how that library provide methods or function for flutter but In android native we have library listener like

```
public interface PurchasesUpdatedListener {
    void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult var1, @Nullable List<Purchase> var2);
}
```

Can you check similar to available in flutter library in that you can verify your response and manage your navigation accordingly.

Comment: Yes in flutter we can implement same listener but what about App is in not opened or App is killed?